# Atualizar div com click

Tags: ajax, div, atualização, click

Estou usando esse código para atualizar uma div da página ao clicar no botão

```
<div id="campo"></div>

function atualiza_campo_usuario(){
    $("#campo").load("http://site.com");
}
```

Porém o que acontece é que as vezes atualiza e as vezes não atualiza, só atualiza clicando 2 vezes,e isso acaba atrapalhando,preciso que toda vez que houver um `clik`, seja atualizado o conteúdo da `div`.

Obs: Deixo claro que o botão que atualiza o conteúdo da `div`, fica em um `modal` que é resgatado através de um `iframe`.

Comment: Rents, podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar mais código? Se colocares um `console.log('click');` dentro dessa função `atualiza_campo_usuario` o log aparece a cada click ou precisas clicar duas vezes?

Comment: Podes adicionar o código do botão? Em que momento adicionas o evento click ao botão?

Comment: Levando em consideração que você adiciona o evento ao botão, onclick ou click no load da pagina com javascript, expeerimente, antes de carregar seu conteúdo, limpar a div: $("#campo").empty(); Mas seria bem interessante ver o código do seu botão.